# How do I know to which core my Python process has been bound?

Tags: python, process

How do I know to which process my Python process has been bound?
Alone these same lines, are child processes going to execute on the same core (i.e. CPU) that the parent is currently executing?

Comment: What do you mean with 'binding to process'? pid? CPU Core?

Comment: @usernaveen I don't believe processes are, in general, tied to a CPU core.

Comment: @millimoose the python process will execute on only one core due to the cpython GIL lock , that is the thing i am asking

Comment: @usernaveen That's only true for any given moment. The OS is certainly free to schedule it on different cores as necessary. This means that the core the process is running on can change *during* a hypothetical function call to determine this. (Barring doing something like disabling interrupts. And even then you could only hypothetically determine which core you were on during this period.) Generally, what is possible is telling the OS to only schedule your process on one specific core, but this is not what you're asking, and also OS-specific.

Comment: @millimoose what about the child processes , are they will execute on the same process or on the other core .Because I am creating the child processes to use multi cores of the cpu.So I wanna conform it

Comment: @usernaveen They will execute wherever the OS puts them, and there is no sane way to control this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Processes and native OS threads are only bound to specific processors if somebody specifically requests for that to happen. By default, processes and threads can (and will) be scheduled on any available processor.

Modern operating systems use pre-emptive multi-threading and can interrupt a thread's execution at any moment. When that thread is next scheduled to run, it can be executed on a different processor. This is known as a context switch. The thread's entire execution context is stored away by the operating system and then when the thread is re-scheduled, the execution context is restored.

Because of all this, it makes no real sense to ask what processor your thread is executing on since the answer can change at any moment. Even during the execution of the function that queried which the current thread's processor.

Again, by default, there's no relationship between the processors that two separate processes execute on. The two processes could execute on the same processor, or different processors. It all depends on how the OS decides to schedule the different threads.

In the comments you state:

> The Python process will execute on only one core due to the GIL lock.

That statement is simply incorrect. For example, a section of Python code would claim the GIL, get context switched around all the available processors, and then release the GIL.

Right at the start of the answer I said alluded to the possibility of binding a process or thread to a particular processor. For example, on Windows you can use `SetProcessAffinityMask` and `SetThreadAffinityMask` to do this. However, it is unusual to do this. I can only recall ever doing this once, and that was to ensure that an execution of `CPUID` run on a specific processor. In the normal run of things, processes and threads have affinity with all processors.

In another comment you say:

> I am creating the child processes to use multi cores of the CPU.

In which case you have nothing to worry about. Typically you would create as many processes as there are logical processors. The OS scheduler is sensible and will schedule each different process to run on a different processor. And thus make the optimal use of the available hardware resources.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer, it is really useful for me

Comment: I don't have a single good book recommendation for you. It all depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: "threads are only bound to specific processors if somebody specifically requests for that to happen".  Any way to query which processor ID your thread/process is bound to in this case?