# Allocating a task to each separate core

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Code:

```
import multiprocessing,pdb

def do_calculation(data):
    print"check %d"%(data)
    return data * 2

def start_process():
    print 'Starting', multiprocessing.current_process().name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = list(range(10)) 
    pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size,
                                initializer=start_process,)
    pool_outputs= pool.map(do_calculation, inputs)
    pool.close() # no more tasks
    pool.join()  # wrap up current tasks
    print 'Pool    :', pool_outputs
```

Output:

```
Starting PoolWorker-1
check 0
check 1
check 2
check 3
check 4
check 5
check 6
check 7
check 8
check 9
Starting PoolWorker-2
Starting PoolWorker-3
Starting PoolWorker-4
Starting PoolWorker-5
Starting PoolWorker-6
Starting PoolWorker-7
Starting PoolWorker-8
Pool    : [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

I want to run a CPU intensive task on each core whereby every core executes an instance. In the above example as representative, I find that only core is doing all the work. (I also care about the output order from the pool.)

Am I doing something wrong or misintrepreting the I/O output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `do_calculation`'s job is not realistic. It run so fast. So it ends even before the other workers start.

If you make the function do more jobs, you will see the difference. For example,

```
import time

def do_calculation(data):
    time.sleep(1)  # <----
    print"check %d"%(data)
    return data * 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Don't how I missed it. Can you please tell if it outputs only once when jobs are complete as also when there are running. I noticed the former while running.

Comment: Can I somehow also print where processor is running a job and print it out?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia, I don't understand the first comment. For the second one, I don't have an idea.

Comment: This seems to answer your second question: [how-do-i-know-to-which-core-my-python-process-has-been-bound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004036/how-do-i-know-to-which-core-my-python-process-has-been-bound)