# How to get actual core number from multiprocessing pool worker?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, threadpool

I have created a multi threaded program using multiprocessing pool. I have a 10 core machine and I want to log the core number (from 1 to 10) for each task. But when I run the program it does the operation in parallel, however the thread numbers I am getting is starting from 3 and goes to 12. Sometimes more than 12. I expect to see the numbers from 1 to 10. How could i achieve that?

This is how pool is defined :

```
with Pool(initializer=_initializer, initargs=(config, cfg)) as p:
        logger.info('Getting conversion queue')
        cursor.execute(const.SQL_S_FILES,{})
        file_ids = cursor.fetchall()
        if file_ids:
            logger.info('Queueing %d files', len(file_ids))
            p.starmap(process, file_ids, chunksize=1)
        else:
            logger.info('Empty queue, rechecking in %ds', SLEEP)
```

And this is I am getting the worker number:

worker_number= multiprocessing.current_process().name.split("-",1)[1]

Comment: Module documentation: The name is a string used for identification purposes only. It has no semantics. Multiple processes may be given the same name. The initial name is set by the constructor. If no explicit name is provided to the constructor, a name of the form ‘Process-N1:N2:...:Nk‘ is constructed, where each Nk is the N-th child of its parent.

Comment: I don't understand why this is so confusing for you. Thread number and physical core are two very different things. Just because you can both enumerate two, doesn't mean they are the same. What if you have 20 threads on 10 cores? The question it self is also weak, "Why? Because they coded it like that." Did they have a technical reason for this, and what it is? I guess that threads 0-2 are taken by standard python processing threads, though I don't really know. Oh, and processes can usually migrate between the cores, so keeping this in sync could be hard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know to which core my Python process has been bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004036/how-do-i-know-to-which-core-my-python-process-has-been-bound)

Comment: so, is there any way to get the core number for each task from those different pool workers?

Comment: No because there isn't even a core number attached to each task to begin with. See the question and answers linked by BoarGules.